# file pointer and instance of struct in a function

Tags: c, function, text-files

I'm trying to study on Textfile topic and I find myself not fully understand how does the declaration of two pointer point to file in void function name modify() work. what I understand is first I need to declare pointer for each file (t1 for item.dat) and (t for tBat.dat). t1 is previously assigned the value by the previous void function name append. then I need to declare an instance of struct for each file. how the modify function work is to read the data from item.dat ( "rb" mode ) and write it on the tBat.dat ( "wb" mode ) then do the modifying on tBat.dat when finished assigned the data back to item.dat by swap the file mode item.dat ( "wb" mode ) tBat.dat ( "rb" mode ). Do I understand the code correctly? If I'm not please correct me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgXqN.jpg)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Bat
{
    int id;
    char name[40];
    int price;
    int stock;
    int buy;
    int left;
};

void append();
void modify();

char fname[]= {"item.dat"};

int main()
{
    int ch;

    while(1)
    {

        printf("==================Batloyee Management System=============\n\n");

        printf("1. Append\n\n");
        printf("2. Modify\n\n");
        printf("any other to Exit\n\n");

        printf("========================================================\n\n");

        printf("\nPlease enter your Choice:");
        scanf("%d",&ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1:
            append();
            break;

        case 2:
            modify();
            break;

        default:
            printf("exist");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void append()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct Bat t, t1;

    fp=fopen(fname,"ab");

    printf("\nEnter ID:");
    scanf("%d",&t1.id);
    printf("\nEnter name:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]",t1.name);
    printf("\nEnter price:");
    scanf("%d",&t1.price);
    printf("\nEnter amount:");
    scanf("%d",&t1.stock);
    fwrite(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
}



void modify()
{
    FILE *fp,*fp1;
    struct Bat t,t1;
    int id,found=0,count=0;

    fp=fopen(fname,"rb");
    fp1=fopen("tBat.dat","wb");

    printf("\nEnter the Bat ID you want to Modify:");
    scanf("%d",&id);

    while(1)
    {
        fread(&t,sizeof(t),1,fp);

        if(feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
        if(t.id==id)
        {
            found=1;
            printf("\nEnter Batloyee ID:");
            scanf("%d",&t.id);

            //fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nEnter Batloyee Name:");
            scanf(" %[^\n]",t.name);
            printf("\nEnter Batloyee Price:");
            scanf("%d",&t.price);
            printf("\nEnter amount:");
            scanf("%d",&t.stock);
            fwrite(&t,sizeof(t),1,fp1);
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&t,sizeof(t),1,fp1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);

    if(found==0)
    {
        printf("Sorry No Record Found\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fp=fopen(fname,"wb");
        fp1=fopen("tBat.dat","rb");

        while(1)
        {
            fread(&t,sizeof(t),1,fp1);

            if(feof(fp1))
            {
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&t,sizeof(t),1,fp);
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is pretty correct but there are a few misunderstandings. Maybe these comes from the "bugs" in the code.

You write:

> t1 is previously assigned the value by the previous void function name append

No, `t1` in the two functions has nothing to do with each other.

The `t1` variable in `append` stop to exist the moment that `append` returns. The value that the user entered is saved in the file (i.e. appended to the file) so the data still exist in the file but **not** in `t1`. `t1` goes out of scope.

And when `modify` is called it's a complete new variable `t1` that is created. It has absolutely nothing to do with the `t1` in the `append` function.

So it's two **different** variables using the same name. That can be done because the variables have different scopes.

Now notice the "bug" in the code...

In `append` you have:

```
struct Bat t, t1;
```

but `t` is never used. So do this change:

```
struct Bat t, t1; -->     struct Bat t1;
```

In `modify` it's kind of the same thing. In `modify` you have:

```
struct Bat t,t1;
```

but `t1` is never used. So do this change:

```
struct Bat t,t1; -->     struct Bat t;
```

These "bugs" (aka unused and thereby unnecessary variables) may cause some confusion.
Besides that, your description seems okay.

BTW: Performance of the `modify` function can be improved but functionallt it seems to work as is.